# apache camel idempotent consumer key removal

Tags: apache-camel

I have a setup like below.

The issue I have is that the key from the Idempotent Repository is not being removed when an exception is thrown (on line stated below) when using `seda` component within `OnException`. When I change to use `direct` within the `OnException` the key is removed from the cache. On both trials the email is also being sent correctly.

My queries are:

1. why is the key not being removed from the repository cache when using `seda` within the `OnException`?
2. is there an issue with using `seda` within the `OnException`?

Here is the routes:

MyRouteClass1

```
onException(Exception.class)
  .setHeader("subjectText", simple("failure email!"))
  .to("seda:notifySupportOnFailure")
  .end();

from("direct:findWorkItems")
    .bean(someService, "findWorkItems")
    .split(body())
      .throttle(1).timePeriodMillis(5000L)
      .to("direct:handleWorkItem")
      .choice().when(header("resultId").isGreaterThan(0))
      .bean(someService, "updateWorkItemToHandled")
      .end();

from("direct:handleWorkItem")
    .idempotentConsumer(simple("${body.workItemId}"), duplicatesRepo)
    .bean(someService, "handleWorkItem")  // e.g. exception would be thrown within here
    .setHeader("resultId", body())
    .end();
```

MyRouteClass2

```
from("seda:notifySupportOnFailure")
  .setHeader("from", simple("sender@mail.com"))
  .setHeader("to", simple("recipient@mail.com"))
  .setBody(simple("Failure:\n ${exception.message} \n\ndetail: \n${body}"))
  .to("smtp://localhost")
  .log("Failure email now sent.")
  .end();
```

I have also attempted another workaround. I have modified the *onException* clause as per below. This does allow the key to be removed from the Repository when the exception is thrown. I am wondering if this is a correct approach ?

```
onException(Exception.class)
  .setHeader("subjectText", simple("failure email!"))
  .multicast().to("seda:notifySupportOnFailure").end()
  .end();
```

Comment: To add some extra info on this. The Repository is of the following:

  IdempotentRepository<String> duplicatesRepo =
      MemoryIdempotentRepository.memoryIdempotentRepository(100);
      
The version of Apache Camel being used is 2.16.2

Answer (score 0):

A work around would be to put the idempotentConsumer call in your parent route 'findWorkItems' and setting the completionEager flag on it to true.

```
onException(Exception.class)
  .setHeader("subjectText", simple("failure email!"))
  .to("seda:notifySupportOnFailure")
  .end();

from("direct:findWorkItems")
    .idempotentConsumer(simple("${body.workItemId}"), duplicatesRepo).completionEager(true)
    .bean(someService, "findWorkItems")
    .split(body())
      .throttle(1).timePeriodMillis(5000L)
      .to("direct:handleWorkItem")
      .choice().when(header("resultId").isGreaterThan(0))
      .bean(someService, "updateWorkItemToHandled")
      .end();

from("direct:handleWorkItem")
    .bean(someService, "handleWorkItem")  // e.g. exception would be thrown within here
    .setHeader("resultId", body())
    .end();
```

Comment: I have tried this work around approach. When I have the _completionEager_ flag set to _true_ then the key is removed from the Repository within the _OnException_ clause.  But is this a correct approach ?